# MySQL table to hold pages that a user likes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How would I set up a table for topics that a user likes? I have a topics tables and a user table (more actually but simplified for a post on here). There is an ever increasing number of topics as they are user generated, how could I allow users to like pages? Would i put the topic's id in the user table or the user's id in the topics table or a create a new likes table? The issue I see is that the number of topics could (potentially) be very large. What could I use to create a system that allows a relationship between a users id and the topics id?

Comment: Do you want to store the topics a user likes, the pages a user likes, or both? Do you also want to store the topics a page has?

Comment: I will be doing one of the two, I left it open because i do not know which method would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could possibly do is a "many to many" table structure

- A unique auto incremented id -   `UINT (10) AUTO_INCREMENT`
- A feild containing the user id -  `UINT (10)` (or what ever matches your main `user_id` field)
- A field containing the "liked" topic id -  `UINT (10)` (or what ever matches your main `topic_id` field)

Both `user_id` and `topic_id` fields would need to be unique together.  That means that there can only be once row for a specific like per user.  This makes sure (on the database side), that a user will not be allowed to like a topic more than once.

Getting a users liked topics would look like this -

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_likes` WHERE `user_id`=USER_ID
```

Getting the users per like would look like this -

SELECT * FROM user_likes`WHERE`topic_id`=TOPIC_ID

---

As others have said in their answers and also [@trevor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704582/mysql-table-to-hold-pages-that-a-user-likes/11704592#comment15525011_11704592) in the comments below -

> Don't forget to add an index on the userid to support retrieval of user liked topics and a separate index on topic is to support the topics per user query - **without these, the queries will get slower as more data is added over time.**

Comment: would this work if a user like 50 different topics? Then would i need a field for every topic id?

Comment: Yes it would work perfectly - You would need a **row** for every topic that every user likes.  If you have 100 users and 5 topics, and every user likes every topic you would have to have 500 **rows** in that table.

Comment: so the table then would an id, the users id and the topic id?

Comment: could you write it out in sql so i can understand it a bit more because i am confused about how the topic_id fits into it.

Comment: `topic_id` is the id of the topic that the user liked.  You mentioned that you already have a topic table.  This id would be your unique id from that table.  A reference to the actual topic that the user liked.

Comment: Don't forget to add an index on the userid to support retrieval of user liked topics and a separate index on topic is to support the topics per user query - without these, the queries will get slower as more data is added over time.

Comment: @Lix, sorry for an outside post to an image, but to clarify you are saying that the table would look like this? [link] (http://s1050.photobucket.com/albums/s416/ryan1234512/?action=view&current=mysql.jpg)

Comment: @ryn - noooo... Not at all.  I was thinking something like this - http://i.imgur.com/kKF3T.png

Comment: ohhhh phew okay, my interpretation it was confusing me haha... so what part on that method compares the pages that a user likes and doesnt like?

Comment: If a row doesn't exist with the user_id and topic_id, then the user doesn't "like" the topic.

Comment: @nic - If you have a new question you can ask it by clicking the [Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.  Make sure to look for an existing post first though - there already might be an answer here!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a new table `UserLikedTopics` or something similar, in which you have two columns, one to keep the `UserId` and one to keep the `TopicId`. For each new topic a user "Likes", you add a new row to the table with the UserId and the TopicId. That way it is easy to keep track of which users likes which topics.

To get whoch topics a certain user like, you simply join the UserLikedTopics with your topics table, and you have a list of all topics a certain user like. You could also make it the other way around and join it on the User table, to get a list of the users that like a certain topic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a 'likes' table. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_likes` (
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `topic_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `topic_id`),
    INDEX `topic_id` (`topic_id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate likes table since it's a separate entity,
link the *likes* table with *users* & *topics* table with **userid** & **topicsid** as *foreign keys* in *likes* table..

It would be good to have a structure like this, later if you dont even want a feature likes, can just remove it without affecting other tables...